# Mean time between dates

Tags: laravel, date, datetime

I have a list of submissions.  Each submission has a `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamp.  I can do something like this to get the dates

```
foreach ($submissions as $submission) {
    var_dump($submission->created_at);
    var_dump($submission->updated_at);
}
```

Say submission one has the `created_at` timestamp of `2017-07-29 23:14:02.000000` and an `updated_at` timestamp of `2017-07-29 23:16:02.000000` I know that this submission took 2 minutes to complete.

What I am trying to calculate is the mean time for all submissions.

Is there any way to achieve this without creating several arrays?

Thanks

and

Comment: You could use the collections class and chain methods to get your result

Comment: show us the query that get `$submissions` !

Comment: `$submissions` I assume is just a model, it has a `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: How do you get `$submissions`, is it with a query? If yes, please add your query to question.

Comment: Hi, I just use get() to obtain all submissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use collection class
$submissions = collect($submissions);

$totalDiffInSeconds = $submissions->map(function ($submission) {
        // diff in seconds
        return $submission->updated_at->getTimestamp() - $submission->created_at->getTimestamp();
    })->sum();

// divide total diff with number of submissions, i.e. mean
$mean = $totalDiffInSeconds / $submissions->count();
```

You can read further on the collections class here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

Comment: @kate-hudson you wouldn't need to do `$submissions = collect($submissions)` if it's already a collection I just thought it might be an array so was explicit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL as your database, you could just generate the average through a query of the difference between the unix timestamps of updated_at and created_at.

```
Model::select(DB::raw("AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at) - 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)) as average_submission_time"))
       ->value('average_submission_time');
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try  [Carbon.  A simple PHP API extension for DateTime.](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)

already with setup with laravel 5.4